# Jar execution using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, swagger

I am working on swagger [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) , so below command to be executed to generate static html files,

> java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar
>   generate   -i http://localhost:8086/swagger.json   -l java   -o
>   samples/client/petstore/java

My problem is how can i trigger above command using **maven**.

i tried with  **exec-maven-plugin** it is asking for **main** class, but i am not sure on the main class(i mean which is main class and where it is)

Please help.

Comment: `main` class is the class containing `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the maven plugin: https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin ?

Comment: @shruti Yes I know it:-),  my problem is if I put that class inside exec-maven plugin it says main method not found.

Comment: @Wim  Yes I tried with the maven plugin which you have mentioned,  but not able to arrive at the required solution. My aim was to generate static html generation.

Answer (score 1):

The main class is SwaggerCodegen.java, as you can see it contains the method:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
```

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/SwaggerCodegen.java

Comment: Thanks Conman for a quick reply,  if I add this as a main in that exec-maven-plugin it says class not found exception, I am specifying main class as io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.  Do I need to mention something else??  Since I am accessing  main class from the jar.

Comment: Strange.  As long as you have a dependency on swagger-codegen, then that package and that class should exist on the class path.  Just as a sanity check, can you make sure that the SwaggerCodegen.class does exist in the jar file you are using?  Its possible that you are using an older version where that class maybe had a different name, or didn't exist?

Comment: Thanks again:-)  Yes I agree with your comment,  basic level investigation I have done. I have added swagger-codegen-cli jar as a dependency,  then it should be available in the class path I guess. Since main class is under src/main/java do I need to mention this?  If so how can I add this attribute..

Comment: Looking at the documentation for usage, are you using the following in your plugin configuration?

<argument>-classpath</argument>
<classpath/>

http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html

Comment: Yes,  html is generating if I use that command in command line which I have mentioned in question,  that's where documentation ends. But I would like do that by maven.

Comment: Thanks for the link:-) ,  I have added the dependency out side the plugin. I have to try the approach mentioned by you.